# Programmatically setting the icon size

Tags: wpf, user-interface

On WPF I am creating a menu item dynamically at run time.

I set the icon from a StreamGeometry that's stored on a ResourceDictionary. Everything works OK but: how do I set the size of the icon?

```
MenuItem menExit = new MenuItem();
menExit.Header = "Exit"; // will be changedlater
menExit.Command = UICommands.CmdExit;
menExit.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(UICommands.CmdExit, CmdExitExecute, CmdExitCanExecute));
menExit.Icon = (StreamGeometry)FindResource("ImgExit");

//SET THE SIZE HERE????????
// Eventually, how do I set the fill color?

menu.Items.Add(menExit);
```

Note, I am doing all this at run time and not in xalm

Comment: The fact that you can directly set a Geometry as Icon makes me think that there is a MenuItem Style. Take a look at the possible Path control in that Style and set its size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to create a path on which you can specify `Height`, `Width` and `Fill` and set your `StreamGeometry` as the `Data` of the path. Then put this `Path` as the icon of the `MenuItem`.

```
var path = new Path
{
    Height = 20,
    Width = 20,
    Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
    Data = (StreamGeometry) FindResource("ImgExit")
};
menExit.Icon = path;
```

Comment: Thnx! I'll try this.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not seeing the icon at all this way. Could it be that it's left or top position is out of bounds or something? The data is being correctly set.

Comment: Got it. Needed only to add:

    path.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;

Answer (score 0):

You can always try this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Convert Geometry to ImageSource, Draws the Geometry on a bitmap surface and centers it.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="geometry"></param>
/// <param name="TargetSize"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
ImageSource Geometry_To_ImageSource(Geometry geometry, int TargetSize)
{
   var rect = geometry.GetRenderBounds(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 0));

   var bigger = rect.Width > rect.Height ? rect.Width : rect.Height;
   var scale = TargetSize / bigger;

   Geometry scaledGeometry = Geometry.Combine(geometry, geometry, GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, new ScaleTransform(scale, scale));
   rect = scaledGeometry.GetRenderBounds(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 0));

   Geometry transformedGeometry = Geometry.Combine(scaledGeometry, scaledGeometry, GeometryCombineMode.Intersect, new TranslateTransform(((TargetSize - rect.Width) / 2) - rect.Left, ((TargetSize - rect.Height) / 2) - rect.Top));

   RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(TargetSize, TargetSize, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

   DrawingVisual viz = new DrawingVisual();
   using (DrawingContext dc = viz.RenderOpen())
   {
      dc.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Black, null, transformedGeometry);
   }

   bmp.Render(viz);

   var mem = new MemoryStream();
   PngBitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
   pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
   pngEncoder.Save(mem);
   var itm = GetImg(mem);
   return itm;
}

BitmapImage GetImg(MemoryStream ms)
{
   var bmp = new BitmapImage();    
   bmp.BeginInit();
   bmp.StreamSource = ms;
   bmp.EndInit();

   return bmp;
}
```